# PGF Math Error: Unknown function when using babel with option ngerman

Tags: tikz-pgf, babel

Here's the MWE for drawing a box with a width matching some text using TikZ:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node [rectangle, draw, minimum width=width("Test")] (testNode) {Test};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Compiling with `pdflatex` (or even `lualatex`) and TeX Live 2019 with the latest updates gives the following error:

```
! Package PGF Math Error: Unknown function `Test' (in 'width("Test")').

See the PGF Math package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...

l.9 ...mum width=width("Test")] (testNode) {Test};
```

Replacing `ngerman` by another language or removing `babel` altogether gets rid of the error. For what it's worth, I've been using this method for years and only recently started seeing this error. Is there something wrong with `babel`?

Comment: Welcome! Add \usetikzlibrary{babel} to the preamble of your document.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat Is it not possible for tikz to do that automaticaly if it recognizes that `babel` with a language `ngerman` is already called?

Comment: @Mensch While it may be possible, it would require major efforts, and inevitably be fragile. It would also slow down the compilation for every user.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat Thanks, that does the trick. Would you perhaps want to post your comment as an answer I could accept?

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat Thanks for your explanation!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the `babel` package redefines the `"`. For this reason, Ti*k*Z has a library that allows one to use the `babel` package and `tikz`, the library's name is also `babel`. If you load it, your code works.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{babel}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node [rectangle, draw, minimum width=width("Test")] (testNode) {Test};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```